# How to detect if the form has been submitted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have form in react.
And I need to detect if the form has successfully been submitted to make a next request in another form

```
const formRef = React.useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formRef && formRef.current) {
      formRef.current.submit();
    }
  }, [formRef]);

 <>
          <form
            id="tdsMethodAcs"
            method="post"
            target="methodAcsFrame"
            action={three_ds_method_url}
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            ref={formRef}
          >
            <input
              type="hidden"
              name="methodAcsFrame"
              value={method_data_packed}
            />
            <input type="submit" />
          </form>
          <iframe name="tdsMethodAcsFrame" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
        </>
```

Comment: You can't know if the form has been submitted successfully since that is being handled by your server. Normally, you would send the post request to the same page and then you would know the status. I think that in your case you actually just want to perform a request instead of submitting a hidden form.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the shortest way is to create a variable in the state to which you change the value when the form is submitted.
Somethink like this:

```
const [formSubmitted, setFormSubmitted];
const onSubmit = () =>{
  //Do stuff
  setFormSubmitted(true);
}
useEffect(()=>{
   //Do another stuff
},[formSubmitted])
```